# While loop on click

Tags: python, graphics

Designing a control graphics window and need it to repeat as long as the window is being clicked in.

Here is the code for the object to be repeated

```
# Limit the bounds of the buttons
def moveBob():
    if 80<x<120 and 10<y<50:
        moveForward= Bob.move(0,-20)
    if 80<x<120 and 100<y<140:
        moveBack= Bob.move(0,20)
    if 25<x<65 and 55<y<95:
        moveLeft= Bob.move(-20,0)
    if 135<x<175 and 55<y<95:
       moveRight= Bob.move(20,0)
```

Here is the "code" for the repeat I am needing to do

```
point= Control.getMouse()
x= point.getX()
y= point.getY()
while click: #need a while loop that will repeat on click
    moveBob
```

I need a way for this code to repeat as long as the user clicks

UPDATE

Moving the statements into the while loop solved it ie:

```
while True:
    point= Control.getMouse()
    x= point.getX()
    y= point.getY()
    moveBob()
```

Comment: If anyone else needs this I found a solution:                                      Moving the statements all into the while loop causes the loop to wait for input each time                                                                                   while True:
    point= Control.getMouse()
    x= point.getX()
    y= point.getY()
    moveBob()

Comment: You have *major* syntax problems in the code you posted. Please clean them up.

Comment: Could you please self answer this question

Comment: @jpmc26 Can you explain. I'm new to Python in an intro programming class

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. You have a line that refers to a method with parentheses, meaning it isn't even being called. There's probably more.

Comment: @jpmc26     I believe I corrected the indentation. It was right in IDLE I had just copied it over poorly. If there is any other syntax errors please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Moving the statements into the while loop solved it ie:

```
while True:
    point= Control.getMouse()
    x= point.getX()
    y= point.getY()
    moveBob()
```